# Handlebars error: 'Handlebars is not defined'

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm new to JS and I have problem in my project. I can't load handlebars. I have the same ReferenceError : handlebars is not defined. I've tried also adding handlebars.js file in src folder but it doesn't work. I would appreciate any help. https://github.com/dzgierski19/pizzeria-project

My JS code :

```
 `const templates = {
    menuProduct: Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector(select.templateOf.menuProduct).innerHTML),
  };`
```

My HTML

```
  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

`

[handlebars error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEQ7k.png)

Comment: Are you referring to handlebars (https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars)? If you are then you need to install it as a dependency (not a dev-dependency).

Comment: I would first check the Network tab in my browser's dev tools to confirm that the request to CloudFlare for the Handlebars script is succeeding (is returning a 200 status code).

Comment: From your error it looks like you are running `script.js` on your node server? This doesn't make sense to me because it looks like all of your JavaScript is intended to be run in the browser. As you are loading Handlebars via a script tag, it can only be available to your scripts run in the browser. For what reason are you using node to execute `script.js`?

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My code runs with live server in VSC, however when I try npm run command it gives me error.

Comment: _Which_ `npm run` command gives you the error?

Comment: npm run watch and npm run test is now OK. I've manually installed stylelint in package.json However I can't run code in VSC, it gives me the same handlebars error..

Comment: How are you running code in VSC?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the handlebars version?
You're using version 4.1.0, but handlebars it's already on version 4.7.7
Theirs any reason to use such an old version?
If you need to use this version, take a look at this version docs to check if it's available and if the methods you're using are right.

At the official doc the say to use @latest version
[image]

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#installation

Comment: I have this version in my project. However I've tried your advice and still get the same error.

Comment: I've cloned your project, and I notice you upload the node_modules to GitHub.
It's not a good practice, it's far better to install the packages based on `package-lock.json` definition.

After removing node_modules and reinstalling the packages, I won't find the related error anymore.

You can use the following command to remove `node_modules` from git
`git rm -fr node_modules`

Let me know if the error is solved

Comment: Ok, I've followed your advice and used git rm -fr node_modules. But what next?

Comment: use `npm i` to reinstall the packages and check if the error is solved

Comment: I've tried that before, but without any result. Does npm run watch command work for you? It gives me error.  ERROR: "test:js" exited with 1.
ERROR: "test" exited with 1.
ERROR: "build" exited with 1.

However using live server extension in VSC runs my code. I don't know what's the problem...

Comment: Ok, so I've modified package.json and installed stylelint manually in NPM. My NPM is running, but I still get an error about handlebars

Comment: I just can't find this error.
I have cloned your project, installed dependencies with `npm i` and then run `npm run watch`, and I can see the project as well.
Did you take another step to find the error?

Comment: I removed all stylelint from package.json a then manually installed it. I reinstalled VSC, disabled all extensions. NPM run watch and NPM run test are working fine, however VSC still gives me an error..

Comment: Is it still the same handlebars error?

Comment: yes, unfortunately PS C:\GIT\pizzeria-project> cd src
PS C:\GIT\pizzeria-project\src> cd js
PS C:\GIT\pizzeria-project\src\js> node script.js
C:\GIT\pizzeria-project\src\js\script.js:47
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) 
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
PS C:\GIT\pizzeria-project\src\js>

Comment: PS C:\GIT\pizzeria-project\src\js> node script.js
C:\GIT\pizzeria-project\src\js\script.js:47
    menuProduct: Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector(select.templateOf.menuProduct).innerHTML),
                 ^

ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined

Comment: Are you trying to run `script.js` with the command `node script.js`?

Comment: yes, because I've uninstalled all other plugins